# Geolocation and Google Chrome Setting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, browser, geolocation

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to automatically find the location of the user and show it on Google map. I use the following source code in my html file.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

My problem is that this code works perfectly in Iinternet Explorer and Mozilla but it is not working in Google Chrome. It shows the following error message "
Error: The Geolocation service failed". 
The problem is that Google Chrome is blocked my page from tracking the location. In "manage location setting", I could not add any exception. 
In content setting/location: I've also allowed all sites to track my physical location but it does not change anything and Chrome is blocked my page from tracking the location anyway.

Answer (score 0):

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_aGmhjtjb0E[1-25-false] scroll a ways down for help on this...thx

Comment: I can not find the answer to my question in that forum, I think they are talking about another issue.